# Typescript array of promises resolving properly in one case but not in another

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, promise, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function that maps each element of an array (email addresses in this case), yielding an array of promises that should resolve to document ids automatically generated by Firebase (i.e. `hAvJ3qPq821tq1q2rrEv, 0tjeKB1aW8jsOAse5fcP`).

```
async function addMultipleParticipants(participant_emails: Array<string>) {
    console.log("Parallelizing participant processing");
    const promises = participant_emails.map(addParticipant);
    const document_ids = await Promise.all(promises);
    console.log("Final document ids: " + document_ids);
    return document_ids;
};
```

Here is the function that returns the document ids, depending on whether it could find an existing document associated with the email address or needed to create a new document.

```
async function addParticipant(email_address: string) {
    try {
        console.log("Querying for person");
        const query = await db.collection('people')
            .where('emails', 'array-contains', email_address)
            .limit(1);
        const querySnapshot = await query.get();
        if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
            console.log("Document exists for email " + email_address);
            // TODO: There is only one, so we shouldn't have to iterate
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(docRef: any) {
                console.log("New document id: " + docRef.id);
                const document_id = docRef.id;
                return document_id;
            });
        } else {
            console.log("Creating person with " + email_address);
            const fields = {emails: [email_address]};
            try {
                const docRef = await db.collection('people').add(fields);
                console.log("New document id: " + docRef.id);
                const document_id = docRef.id;
                return document_id;
            } catch (err) {
                console.log("Error adding document:", err);
            }
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error getting document:", err);
    }
};
```

When all participant emails don't exist in documents yet, the functions work as expected, and `console.log()` outputs `Final document ids: hAvJ3qPq821tq1q2rrEv, 0tjeKB1aW8jsOAse5fcP`.

However, when at least one email address is associated with an existing document, the promises from `addParticipant()` do not resolve to anything, and `console.log()` outputs `Final document ids: ,`.

In this scenario, what do I need to do to ensure that the array of promises resolves properly in `addMultipleParticipants()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out with some hints from @basarat.  There should be an explicit return for the first result, rather than a for-loop: `return querySnapshot.docs[0].id;`.  The full modified function is below:

```
async function addParticipant(email_address: string) {
    try {
        console.log("Querying for person");
        const query = await db.collection('people')
            .where('emails', 'array-contains', email_address)
            .limit(1);
        const querySnapshot = await query.get();
        if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
            console.log("Document exists for email " + email_address);
            return querySnapshot.docs[0].id;
        } else {
            console.log("Creating person with " + email_address);
            const fields = {emails: [email_address]};
            try {
                const docRef = await db.collection('people').add(fields);
                console.log("New document id: " + docRef.id);
                const document_id = docRef.id;
                return document_id;
            } catch (err) {
                console.log("Error adding document:", err);
            }
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error getting document:", err);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

> When all participant emails don't exist in documents yet, the functions work as expected, and console.log() outputs Final document ids: hAvJ3qPq821tq1q2rrEv, 0tjeKB1aW8jsOAse5fcP

This is because it resolves to the following return statement:

```
return document_id;
```

> However, when at least one email address is associated with an existing document, the promises from addParticipant() do not resolve to anything

Because it *doesn't* return anything. The last statement you have is :

```
        // TODO: There is only one, so we shouldn't have to iterate
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(docRef: any) {
            console.log("New document id: " + docRef.id);
            const document_id = docRef.id;
            return document_id;
        });
```

It is *not* a return of any id. It is simply a `forEach`. Example fix would be like:

```
        // Return the id
        return querySnapshot[0].document_id;
```

Comment: Thanks, seems promising!  (No pun intended.)  However, when I tried `return querySnapshot[0].document_id`, it caused an error (`TypeError: Cannot read property 'document_id' of undefined`).  I should point out that `document_id` is not a field in the document - what I really want is the id of a specific document in the `people` collection.

Comment: I also tried `return querySnapshot.getDocuments()[0].getId();`, based on [Google's documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/QuerySnapshot.html#getDocuments()), but it threw this error: `TypeError: querySnapshot.getDocuments is not a function`.

Answer (score 1):

With `Promise.all` if even 1 promise fails, you won't get the result of either. Take the following example:

```
const get = async () => {
    return Promise.all([
        new Promise((res, rej) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                res('data!')
            }, 1000)
        }),
        new Promise((res, rej) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                rej('error!')
            }, 2000)
        })
    ]);
}

const start = async () => {
    const response = await get()
    console.log(response)
}

start()
```

You will just get an `Uncaught (in promise) error!` error.

Now if you want to get around this to get at least something back, you could potentially use `catch` for each promise like so:

```
const get = async () => {
    return Promise.all([
        new Promise((res, rej) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                res('data!')
            }, 1000)
        }).catch(err => {
            return null
        }),
        new Promise((res, rej) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                rej('error!')
            }, 2000)
        }).catch(err => {
            return null
        })
    ]);
}

const start = async () => {
    const response = await get()
    console.log(response)
}

start()
```

This will then give you `["data!", null]` and you can handle the `null` as you see fit.